# Ubuntu systemd error exited on sudo reboot

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Greetings. I'm currently automating a python script to run on boot of Ubuntu system. Everything works fine when i set up my service and manually starting it. But when i reboot my system and checked the status i encountered this error.
[image]

Here is mysmtp.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Smtp Service
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=idle
WorkingDirectory=<my path script dir>
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python smtp.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here is the command i execute:

```
sudo chmod +x <my path script>
sudo systemctl enable mysmtp.service
sudo systemctl start mysmtp.service
```

Thanks

Comment: Seems like more of a config question so might it be a better fit for https://askubuntu.com/ ?

Comment: @PaulRooney Hi Sir yes i will try to post a question on askubuntu.com -thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this...

> ```
> sudo chmod +x <my path script>
> ```

Does your script start with a shebang? `#!/usr/bin/env python`?

If so, you do not need to specify `/usr/bin/python` is your `ExecStart`, or really `WorkingDirectory`.

Give the full path in the `ExecStart` to  `<my path script dir>/smtp.py`

Comment: my mistake here, yup it was sudo chmod +x <my path script dir>/smtp.py

I already did the inputting the full path on ExecStart but still when i reboot my ubuntu system and checking the status it was the error i've screened shot.

Comment: Well, your screenshot currently says "can't find file". So, is the file being deleted when you reboot? Or the service can't read the directory where the file exists?

Comment: And owned by your user, I'm guessing? The system init process might not be running as root

Comment: when i check by ls -l /home/<myusername>/smtp.py
the result is 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 <myusername> <myusername> 862 Jun 21 10:12 smtp.py

is it correct?

Comment: That's fine for the script, now what about `ls -l /home`?

Comment: I think you might be able to have something like this to use your user account https://stackoverflow.com/a/26565328/2308683